# Exchange 2013 Autodiscover with Nginx

Tags: exchange, autodiscover

I have a problem regarding the Exchange Autodiscover service. I try to implement the service with Nginx because we have no Exhange Server anymore and use Postfix.

Now i have installed all configurations and deliver a complete XML Autodiscover file with my Webserver. It's working well but i have one problem i need the complete email as "username" to login to our mailserver.

I have found a a schema:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb204278(v=exchg.150).aspx

and there are options for `LoginName`, `DomainName` and `DomainRequired`. My return looks like the following:

```
<Protocol>
<Type>SMTP</Type>
<Server>smtp.xxxx.de</Server>
<Port>587</Port>
<TLS>on</TLS>
<SPA>off</SPA>
<AuthRequired>on</AuthRequired>
<LoginName>JohnDoe@sample.com</LoginName>
</Protocol>
```

But when i make an Autodiscover with Outlook Outlook add me automatically the username without the domain.

[image]

**Edit: I use the exactly that script mentioned in the first comment here. My LoginName is set correctly but its not set in Outlook. Normally you can login without the domain but i need its because i have more then one domain behind them.**

[Is there a way to use the Autodiscover feature without Exchange?](https://serverfault.com/questions/244660/is-there-a-way-to-use-the-autodiscover-feature-without-exchange)

Comment: i use exactly that script ;) and its not working. My Server returns exactly that part and its correct with the username as complete email but outlook didn't care about.

Comment: <DomainRequired>on</DomainRequired> ? (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/bb204103(v=exchg.80).aspx)

Comment: I have tried that but no effect. I've set the Domain and DomainRequired but outlook still ignores it.

Comment: Change the loginname to domain\username, can you trick the xml for that ?